# Is a foreach loop not able to handle references in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I've just noticed that you cannot deal with references in a foreach loop. Take this code example:

```
    $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $foo = array();


    foreach($arr as $a) {
        $foo[] = &$a;
    }

    var_dump($foo);
```

Surprisingly, the output is `array(5) { [0]=> &int(5) [1]=> &int(5) [2]=> &int(5) [3]=> &int(5) [4]=> &int(5) }`.

However, I expected a copy of `$arr`. I can only a

```
   for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
      $foo[] = &$arr[$i];
   }

   var_dump($foo);
```

Output: `array(5) { [0]=> &int(1) [1]=> &int(2) [2]=> &int(3) [3]=> &int(4) [4]=> &int(5) }`

Why is such behavior desirable?

Comment: My question is: why are you using pointers? It is 2015 :)

Comment: I thought to be obliged to use pointers due to "bind_param" of mysqli.

Comment: This isn't the `foreach` causing it, but the *local* `$a` variable you are creating and *its storage you are referencing* on assignment.

Comment: This means that $a is created once and in each iteration it is assigned a new value? I thought $a is a new variable in each iteration.

Comment: Foreach only updates the target variable `$a`. It's only *created* once in that scope. The `=>$a` assignment in each loop merely updates the zval. Which is why `&$a` assigns a reference to the same variable store, and only the last iterations´ value sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temporary variable `$a` changes each iteration until it finally equals 5, so references to it are 5.  This will give you the desired behaviour:

```
foreach($arr as &$a) {
    $foo[] = &$a;
}
```

This will reference `$a` to the actual array values.